# Why am I only able to read/processs one file from an SI MessageSource?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, dsl

Looking at this flow...

```
public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
    return this.invoked.getAndSet(true) ? null : new Date();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mainFlow() {
    JsonObjectMapper<?, ?> jsonObjectMapper = new Jackson2JsonObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    // @formatter:off
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(
                    amazonS3InboundSynchronizationMessageSource(),
                    e -> e.poller(p -> p.trigger(this::nextExecutionTime))
            )
            .channel(LoggingUtils.createLoggingMessageChannel("File:::"))
            .transform(new FileToInputStreamTransformer())
            .split(new FileSplitter(), null)
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)))
            .transform(Transformers.fromJson(persistentType(), jsonObjectMapper))
            .handle(LoggingUtils.createLoggingMessageHandler("Parsed JSON record #"))
            //.handle(jdbcRepositoryHandler())
            //.publishSubscribeChannel(p -> p.subscribe(persistenceSubFlow()))
            .get();
    // @formatter:on
}
```

**Why is it that I'm only able to read one file?**

Even though the configured `MessageSource` (a `AmazonS3InboundSynchronizationMessageSource`) writes more than one file to local directory.

*Sample console output*

```
2015-09-11 09:52:59,856 [task-scheduler-1] org.springframework.integration.aws.s3.InboundFileSynchronizationImpl INFO Sync completed
2015-09-11 09:52:59,860 [task-scheduler-1] org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler INFO Event: [File:::] - Message: [GenericMessage [payload=/Users/cphi/development/projects/expedia/git/luis-data-migration-service/target/s3-dump/RatePlanLevelRestrictionLog/2015/08/23/00/2015-08-22-23-58-0.302402118982895.gz, headers={id=e58c332b-c217-8059-c4e8-09bba2c430a0, timestamp=1441990379859}]]
2015-09-11 09:52:59,918 [pool-2-thread-8] org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler INFO Event: [Parsed JSON record #] - Message: [GenericMessage [payload=RatePlanLevelRestrictionLog[roomTypeId=,ratePlanId=201744463,stayDate=Wed Sep 02 17:00:00 PDT 2015,ratePlanLevel=0,hotelId=4469515,rprLogSeqNum=16,logActionTypeId=2,sellStateId=1,startAllowed=,endAllowed=,fplosMaskArrival=,fplosMaskStayThrough=,doaCostPriceChanged=,supplierUpdateDate=Sat Aug 22 07:57:24 PDT 2015,supplierUpdateTuid=68630676,createDate=Sat Aug 22 07:57:24 PDT 2015,changeRequestId=31461011173,changeRequestSourceId=], headers={sequenceNumber=8, file_name=2015-08-22-23-58-0.302402118982895.gz, sequenceSize=0, correlationId=16e44a80-2669-b2bf-f2bf-f12fe6bb4510, file_originalFile=/Users/cphi/development/projects/expedia/git/luis-data-migration-service/target/s3-dump/RatePlanLevelRestrictionLog/2015/08/23/00/2015-08-22-23-58-0.302402118982895.gz, id=6b866d25-07e8-22a4-381c-d26205393f3b, timestamp=1441990379898}]]
2015-09-11 09:52:59,919 [pool-2-thread-3] org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler INFO Event: [Parsed JSON record #] - Message: [GenericMessage [payload=RatePlanLevelRestrictionLog[roomTypeId=,ratePlanId=1030513,stayDate=Wed Aug 26 17:00:00 PDT 2015,ratePlanLevel=0,hotelId=1615126,rprLogSeqNum=6,logActionTypeId=2,sellStateId=0,startAllowed=,endAllowed=,fplosMaskArrival=,fplosMaskStayThrough=,doaCostPriceChanged=,supplierUpdateDate=Sat Aug 22 07:57:35 PDT 2015,supplierUpdateTuid=46712703,createDate=Sat Aug 22 07:57:35 PDT 2015,changeRequestId=31461014045,changeRequestSourceId=], headers={sequenceNumber=3, file_name=2015-08-22-23-58-0.302402118982895.gz, sequenceSize=0, correlationId=16e44a80-2669-b2bf-f2bf-f12fe6bb4510, file_originalFile=/Users/cphi/development/projects/expedia/git/luis-data-migration-service/target/s3-dump/RatePlanLevelRestrictionLog/2015/08/23/00/2015-08-22-23-58-0.302402118982895.gz, id=ddf1ee98-55c4-81de-af77-a886a340fe07, timestamp=1441990379897}]]
2015-09-11 09:52:59,919 [pool-2-thread-2] org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler INFO Event: [Parsed JSON record #] - Message: [GenericMessage [payload=RatePlanLevelRestrictionLog[roomTypeId=,ratePlanId=163007,stayDate=Fri Dec 11 16:00:00 PST 2015,ratePlanLevel=0,hotelId=897973,rprLogSeqNum=3,logActionTypeId=2,sellStateId=0,startAllowed=,endAllowed=,fplosMaskArrival=,fplosMaskStayThrough=,doaCostPriceChanged=,supplierUpdateDate=Sat Aug 22 07:57:16 PDT 2015,supplierUpdateTuid=46712703,createDate=Sat Aug 22 07:57:16 PDT 2015,changeRequestId=31461009374,changeRequestSourceId=], headers={sequenceNumber=2, file_name=2015-08-22-23-58-0.302402118982895.gz, sequenceSize=0, correlationId=16e44a80-2669-b2bf-f2bf-f12fe6bb4510, file_originalFile=/Users/cphi/development/projects/expedia/git/luis-data-migration-service/target/s3-dump/RatePlanLevelRestrictionLog/2015/08/23/00/2015-08-22-23-58-0.302402118982895.gz, id=d7d7a418-6593-bc57-fc7d-e181778be0c8, timestamp=1441990379899}]]   
...
```

*Directory contents*

```
.../target/s3-dump/RatePlanLevelRestriction
+- 2015
+-- 08
+--- 23
+---- 00
+----- 2015-08-22-23-58-0.302402118982895.gz
+----- 2015-08-22-23-58-0.302992661055088.gz
+----- 2015-08-22-23-58-0.303107496339691.gz
```

If you're curious here's the gists for:

- `LoggingUtils`:  https://gist.github.com/fastnsilver/82f242dd5b42bfd118e8
- `amazonS3InboundSynchronizationMessageSource()` config: https://gist.github.com/fastnsilver/fb750c02b58a04686509

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase `maxMessagesPerPoll` on the poller (default is 1).

Comment: If I do that; how would I know what max messages should be? Each synchronized directory could contain a variant number of files.  I guess you're placing a limit of the number of files that can be processed in one poll? I tried, and it did process more than 1 file, but I'm still trying to reconcile if I set `maxMessagesPerPoll` too low I'd still have the original problem? I also tried `p.trigger(Pollers.fixedDelay(2000)` and saw that the same files were polled, but that they were not reprocessed downstream b/c of the way the `InboundFileSynchronizer` works inside the S3 `MessageSource` impl.

Comment: You just need to set `mmpp` large enough (or `-1` for unlimited - meaning keep processing files until no new ones are encountered).

Comment: Thanks Gary! But shouldn't `-1` be the default?

Comment: See [the important note in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-adapter-namespace-inbound) that explains why it defaults to 1 for inbound channel adapters - the framework can't make any assumptions about how a particular `MessageSource` might behave so it defaults to 1 for safety. We could consider adding some property to `MessageSource` but many users actually want to pace the rate at which files are processed, and `mmpp` already gives you complete control.